# Select year from dropdown in vue2-daterange-picker

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue2-daterange-picker

I would like to add "Select year from dropdown in vue2-daterange-picker".
I'm using this plugin in my vuejs project: https://innologica.github.io/vue2-daterange-picker/#usage
Currently, It has only input number of the year.
[image]

Comment: Kindly have the look at the docs in the props section. I think `show-dropdowns` will solve your issue

Comment: Docs said, setting show-dropdowns to true to make range Month and Year, but it's only Month as dropdown and Year become input number (not dropdown)